# Filtering text in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa

I have an `NSTableView` in which I need to be able to intercept keyboard events within an editable cell and replace the cell with strings.  For example, press "a" and have the "a" intercepted and the value "Alpha" assigned when the table reloads.  The actual situation is a bit more complex in that I'm also handling HID devices, but that's a whole other story.  Suffice it to say, I just want to be able to go into edit mode and stop the keyboard-generated values from being displayed.

The latter part of this (displaying "Alpha") is easy, but I can't figure out the first part of the problem.  If I subclass the table and make it first responder, I can receive the `keyDown:` event, but once the user double-clicks on a cell and starts typing, this goes silent.

Since none of the other `NSTableView` components (`NSCell`, `NSTextFieldCell`, etc) derive from `NSResponder`, I'm assuming there is an `NSTextField` buried in there somewhere.

So, what's the best way to filter text once the user goes into cell edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

As always happens: after working on this for eight hours, reading all the docs five times, and then resorting to the net, I find the answer five minutes later:

```
- (BOOL)textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)textObject.
```

Sorry to consume bandwidth.